# Preserve order of dataframe after merge

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, merge

I have a dataframe `df1`, which needs to have a new column `'h[mm]'` appended. The values in the new `'h[mm]'` should be looked up in `df2` depending on values in `df1`'s `'Profile'` column. The situation could be compared to Excel's 'vlookup' or 'index/match'.

I have successfully added the new column `'h[mm]'` with the correct values to `df1`. However, it changes the order of the original `df1`, which is not desired in my case.

A simplified reproducible version of the dataframes `df1` and `df2` are:

```
pile_type = ['P01', 'P20', 'P05', 'P23', 'P04', 'P01']
profile = ['HE200A', 'HE220A', 'HE240B', 'NaN', 'HE200A', 'HE300B']
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'Pile_type': pile_type, 'Profile': profile})

profile_database = ['HE200A', 'HE220A', 'HE240B', 'HE500B', 'HE300B']
profile_height_database = [190, 210, 240, 500, 300]
df2 = pd.DataFrame({'Profile': profile_database, 'h[mm]': profile_height_database})
```

The closest I came to a solution is using `pd.merge_ordered()`:

```
df_mo= pd.merge_ordered(df1, df2, left_by='Profile')
```

Which still does not preserve the original order of `df1` in the resulting `df_mo`:

```
print('df1:', df1)
print('df2:', df2)
print('df_mo:', df_mo)

df1:    Pile_type Profile
0       P01       HE200A
1       P20       HE220A
2       P05       HE240B
3       P23       NaN
4       P04       HE200A
5       P01       HE300B

df2:  Profile h[mm]
0     HE200A  190
1     HE220A  210
2     HE240B  240
3     HE500B  500
4     HE300B  300

df_mo:  Pile_type Profile  h[mm]
0       P01       HE200A   190.0
1       P04       HE200A   190.0
2       P20       HE220A   210.0
3       P05       HE240B   240.0
4       P23       NaN      NaN
5       P01       HE300B   300.0
```

I have also tried the standard `pd.merge()` without luck.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use: `df1.merge(df2, how='left')`

As @Graipher points out, the `how` parameter is what controls the order of the resulting merged `DataFrame`

> how : {‘left’, ‘right’, ‘outer’, ‘inner’}, default ‘inner’
>
> - left: use only keys from left frame, similar to a SQL left outer join;
>     **preserve key order**

---

```
df1.merge(df2, on='Profile', how='left')

  Pile_type Profile  h[mm]
0       P01  HE200A  190.0
1       P20  HE220A  210.0
2       P05  HE240B  240.0
3       P23     NaN    NaN
4       P04  HE200A  190.0
5       P01  HE300B  300.0
```

Comment: The `how='left'` part is what actually makes it keep the order